# Converting an array of strings into and object?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a list of strings.

```
String result[] = { "1=AccountId93",
                "10188=930.0", "10190=Mkt930", "1=AccountId94",
                "10188=940.0", "10190=Mkt940", "1=AccountId95",
                "10188=950.0", "10190=Mkt950" };
```

I want to put list into an array of objects where by the object is e.g AccountId93,930.0,Mkt930

How can I reorder this array??? N.b there is name value pairs to work with but a map will not work as the key values will overwrite each other

Comment: It would help if you could explain what the different elements in the array are and what you want the target Account Object to look like

Comment: I thought I did sorry. Result is a list of strings. tag 1 = accountID tag 10188 = Price tag 10190 = marketPrice These three things make up the Account Object. So there currently just a list. but the first three strings will make up object instance 1. The second three will make up instance 2 and so on

Comment: A basic way to go about your problem with such a poorly constructed list, would be to create an object that has the three requisite properties; iterate through the list (assuming you need all the items), instantiating an object for each three items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i+=3) {
   String value1 = result[i  ].split("=")[1];
   String value2 = result[i+1].split("=")[1];
   String value3 = result[i+2].split("=")[1];
   items.add(new Item(value1, value2, value3));
}
```

This will do it. `Item` is your class that represents a data set stored in the array of strings.

Comment: Yes the tags are strictly ordered. Thanks folks